# swap regex matches

Tags: vim

How can I swap the match and replace shown below?
//each line contains 5 s///g, shown below with only 2 s///g

```
:silent! %s/ó/&oacute;/g | :silent! %s/ú/&uacute;/g
```

to

```
:silent! %s/&oacute;/ó/g | :silent! %s/&uacute;/ú/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim: try this (using + as a delimiter). Note that this will not handle the special meanings of characters.

```
:s+silent! %s/\zs\(\%([^\\/]\|\\.\)*\)/\(\%([^\\/]\|\\.\)*\)\ze/g+\2/\1+g
```

With the verymagic option (`\v`):

```
:s@\vsilent! \%s/\zs(%([^\\/]|\\.)*)/(%([^\\/]|\\.)*)\ze/g@\2/\1@g
```

Comment: I think changing the delimiter and using the very magic so it gets easier see `:h \v` or follow this [link](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html).

Comment: @user107745: That is an option. I am expanding the answer.